# Creating web services in spring mvc 2.5

Tags: spring, rest

My project is in spring mvc 2.5 and MySQL as db. Now I want to create a REST web services for this project and expose some of the methods. Can any one help me which approach to follow? I have read several ways so I am totally confused now.

How about spring ws, is it proper way? If yes then can you provide me some useful links for that? or if there is some other way then please anyone can provide me some useful links for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How about spring ws, is it proper way?

No.  Spring-WS is for building SOAP web services, not REST.

Plain Spring MVC provides ways to build REST-style web services.  See [2.5.6.1 Comprehensive REST support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.html#d0e1188)

Comment: Hello.. Thank you for your reply. But please can you provide me an example. Because i did lot of googling and read many blogs but still i didn't got anything.